# Where can I find the most recent dictionary of standard Linux Audit event fields?

Tags: security, logs, audit, standard, linux-audit

I am writing a converter which takes Linux Audit logs as input. I tried to find the most recent dictionary file where all the valid names of the fields are defined.

I've found [such a file](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/field-dictionary.txt)[[1](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/field-dictionary.txt)] but the [main website](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit)[[2](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit)] says:

> Specs
>
> The specifications have [moved to github](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki). The following will be left in place for a while and then removed.

I cannot find these information on the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki)[[3](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki)] of the Linux Audit project.

Is the file[[1](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/field-dictionary.txt)] still the most recent and valid source of information?

---

Links:

1. https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/field-dictionary.txt
2. https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit
3. https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your github link, follow "Audit Event Parsing Library" which has a link the the dictionary at https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/blob/master/specs/fields/field-dictionary.csv

The raw CSV version is at

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/master/specs/fields/field-dictionary.csv